# Thermodynamics of flow boiling

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

I am trying to understand how the process of flow boiling would look like on a $T$-$S$ (temperature-entropy) plot. Consider the flow of a liquid through a straight pipe which is heated by an external source. The liquid enters as a saturated liquid at some pressure. Soon after entering the pipe, vapor starts forming. Assume that the length of the pipe and the heat source are selected in a way that the fluid exits as saturated vapor. The process is expected to be isothermal and isobaric because of phase change. But it is well established that fluid (both single- and two-phase) experiences pressure drop along the flow length due to friction, momentum change etc.

I know that the $T$-$S$ plots are defined for when the phases are in equilibrium. Is thermal equilibrium the only requirement or should the phases be stagnant as well? Following up on this, is it even valid to plot this process on a $T$-$S$ plot?

P.S. I stumbled upon this question while trying to depict a pumped loop system, with an evaporator and a condenser, on a $T$-$S$ plot. The working liquid (a refrigerant) undergoes flow boiling in the evaporator and flow condensation in the condenser.

Comment: Suppose it were not boiling.  Do you know how to determine the entropy change for this situation (assuming that the fluid exits at equilibrium)?

Comment: As a single-phase liquid flows through the pipe, its temperature increases as it is being heated but its pressure drops as well due to friction. I believe that the entropy increases and if it makes sense, it can be plotted on a T-S plot with the process line showing an increase in temperature and moving to lower isobars.

Comment: What about viscous heating?

Comment: Yes, even viscous heating would increase the liquid temperature. Both viscous heating and heat transfer across a finite temperature difference will increase the system entropy.

Comment: How would you handle it  if the fluid exited with a radial temperature profile?

Comment: Apologies for the late response. Back to your comment: that's a good point. I guess that points back to my question of whether it is even possible to depict such a flow, which is being heated, to be represented on a T-S plot.